# Method works when it's called using onkeydown HTML attribute, but does not work using jquery onkeyup event handler

Tags: jquery, jsp

Why is this code not working, although it works when `sendinfo` is called within the input field using `onkeydown="sendInfo()"`?

I've used this within the same jsp page

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function ()    
    {  
        $("#emp_id").onkeyup(function ()  
        {
            sendInfo();  
        });  
    });  

    var request;  
    function sendInfo()  
    {  
        var v = document.getElementById("emp_id").value; 
        // emp_id is the id of input text field
        var url = "ajax_validate.jsp?sendo=" + v;  

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {  
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
        }  
        try {  
            request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;  
            request.open("GET", url, true);  
            request.send();  
        } catch (e) {  
            alert("Unable to connect to server");  
        }  
    }  

    function getInfo() {  
        if (request.readyState === 4) {  
            var val = request.responseText;  
            var ok = "ID not verified..!";  
            if (ok === val)  
            {  
                document.getElementById('lala').innerHTML = val;   
                // don't worry about this id i've used it from the div 
                // to receive the response form servlet for validation
            } else  
            {  
                document.getElementById('lala').innerHTML = val;  
            } 
        }  
    }  

</script>
```

Comment: Any error in your console? Is jquery included? Is there an id emp_id on the input field? ..?